# What is the opposite word to "indent"—"outdent" or "unindent"?

Tags: word-choice, programming, technology, editing

I'm looking for the opposite word to "indent." Is it "outdent", or is it "unindent"?

Corresponding to "Tab" and "Shift Tab" in most editors.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want the word to mean; "outdent" and "unindent" have ***two different meanings*** which can both be taken to be the opposite of "indent". Is the opposite of a "hill" a "plain" or a "valley"?

Comment: I think you're looking for *unformatted* or *unindented*. That is not formatted or indented respectively. But, perhaps you mean a *margin* or a *gutter margin*?

Comment: Partly due to the popularity of Microsoft and Adobe, outdent is commonly used in commercial text editors. In my experience, though, unindent (often hyphenated) is used to describe the Shift + Tab key combo in Sublime, Eclipse, and TEX. I always say un-indent since outdent also refers to a specific formatting, called a hanging paragraph.

Comment: **Indent** in to the right of margin, **outdent** is to the left of margin, but **unindent** is to undo an indent. Newb is right in his answer. Both *outdent* & *unindent* are used, and have different meanings. jiyinyiyong, These are not words used in general English writing. Please refer to your software Help, or Google the definitions.

Comment: @PeterShor I misunderstood these words. It's `unindent` here as the only anwser said.

Comment: Example usage of "outdent" in the context can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12478748/55075, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4148150/55075 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/14984460/55075.

Comment: In publishing the opposite of indenting is called "left-justifying" or "running flush left"; I don't know what it's called in computer programming.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Corresponding to "Tab" and "Shift Tab" in most editors.

In that case you'll want *unindent*, as it reverses the *indent* action, and as *outdent* refers to a (usually left-) hanging block of text.

Answer (score 7):

***Dedent*** or corrupted ***Outdent*** is correct.
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dedent

(Disclaimer: The following is "from what I know")

Latin ***in-*** (alt. ***im-***) is a prefix, not to be confused with the english word ***in*** (which is just shorthand for inside/inward/within). But we do commonly confuse the two, which is why ***Outdent*** is a valid word.

The prefix ***in-***, when used with verbs, signifies "what is being done unto" rather than "what we do". (i.e. the object's perspective, figuratively "from itself/within", which is probably why people confuse the two words).

When used with a noun or adjective, ***in-*** is typically a negator or declaration of absence (unless it's a verbal noun/adjective, in which case the verb dictates the meaning). This is similar to how the - sign in math is used to describe a negative number (i.e. ***inactive***/***inaction*** "not active/acting" or ***implosive***/***imposing*** "negatively explosive/exposing", which showcases another reason why we mistake ***in*** for ***in-***, because an implosion is effectively an "inwards explosion").

Here it becomes even more confusing, because we often use latin verbs as nouns and adjectives (because the english syntax, and thus vocabulary, is different from the latin one). So while the noun for the verb import should, for instance, be importation or importment, we just say "an import" or "something imported" instead. Neither importation or importment are correct english words, afaik.

I.e. ***indent*** means "to have toothed into", whereas noun ***dent*** means "tooth" and verb ***edent*** means "to tooth into". However, ***edent*** is not a valid english word because indent or dent is used instead. Because, you know, reasons... "To tooth" is a figurative way of saying to strike, blow, or sink into.

In other words, indent isn't even a noun, but a verb that we sometimes use as a noun. The correct noun of indent, in english, is indentation or indentment. There's no such thing as "an indent".

Another way to explain the logic is that you cannot technically dent something "the other way" because a dent is still a dent, and it's either there or it's not. Running is similar - you can change your direction, but you'll still be running.

**Other words:** Invent/event, invoke/evoke, Inject/eject, Involve/evolve
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_words_with_English_derivatives

Answer (score 2):

The opposite of *indent* is *outdent*, according to [Christopher Hoot](https://www.uakron.edu/art/our-people/bio-detail.dot), graduate of Yale University and graphic design instructor at the University of Akron.

*Outdent* is modelled on *indent*, replacing *in* with its opposite, *out*.

It refers to *multident* -> multiple “*dents*” in a paragraph.

Example usage:

> You may choose to indent or outdent this paragraph or line of type.

Verb *outdent* is to indent negatively, bring towards the margin.

> By default, the summary tasks are bold and outdented, and the subtasks are indented beneath them.

You can also use *de-indent*.

Source:

- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/outdent)

Answer (score 1):

**Ex** and **out** have the same meaning, so **exdent** has exactly the same meaning as **outdent** (an outward space) and it was used commonly in my typography work. **Un** means to reverse something, undo the indent, or effectively zero it out--no indent at all, either in or out. So exdent or outdent are the words you seek, with outdent more commonly used and understood.

Answer (score 0):

-dent- meaning tooth?
--indent-- bite mark
It is a version of a hanging indent folks (hanging tooth).
I realize that all words are made up at one point or another, but outdent?  A different approach is needed for this. A hanging intent moves the rest of your paragraph in by the distance of 1 tab. So that is technically not what we are after.

We also can't use relationship closer to the margin because in most cases (except that of hanging indent) we are not moving closer . . . but rather into the margin.

Would it then become a extradent?
Alternatively why not protrusion+indent= prodent?
If the opposite of a dent in English is a bump or a bubble then why not go there? Bumpdent?

We could say "tab left" or "negative tab" or even "hanging tooth" and have a much more accurate descriptor. I just can't get behind outdent.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/411800)

Answer (score -1):

Upon more reflection on this topic I propose the following terminology:

- Dent (same as indent): Add space such that the line starts further inside the surrounding text block.
- Bump (same as outdent): Remove space such that the line starts further outside the surrounding text block.

This follows from the fact that a bump is the opposite of a dent.

"Please dent line 13", "We should really bump this block".

Of course this is partially a joke, seeing as "bumping" something can already mean a few things.