# What is the opposite of indented (because "exdent[ed]" appears not to be a word)?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've always used the word "exdented" when describing a paragraph of text (or, more usually, a section of computer code) where the first line is set further left than the remainder of the paragraph/block - essentially the opposite of "indented".

However, it appears that exdent isn't really a word - it's not in the Oxford dictionaries, Websters, or Wiktionary, as far as I can tell. So, is there a better word? Is there one that typographers and typesetters use?

(In the ancient `UNIX` text formatting package `nroff`, the `-ms` macro set included a `.XP` command to achieve the effect. This stood for "exdented paragraph" and I suspect that's where my usage comes from, but that doesn't mean it's the right term!)

Oblig. sample sentence: "The first line of the code block should be *<exdented>* to identify a new block"

Comment: I use *outdented*.

Comment: Related: *[What is the opposite word to “indent”—“outdent” or “unindent”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149511)*

Comment: The word *outdented*, though uncommon, seems to be the most widely accepted for general use.  You do bring computer languages into the picture, however.  In connection with computer programming, and specifically in connection with the indention-sensitive Python programming language, the standard term is *dedent* / *dedented*.

Comment: Sounds like it's better suited to [ux.SE], but I could be wrong.

Comment: "Ancient" is stretching it.

Comment: Given the comparatively short duration of the history of electronic digital computing, I think "ancient" is quite a good description of a program written over 30 years ago. (Also, SCO also officially describe any version of UNIX up to Version 7 as an "Ancient UNIX" - nroff was written for Version 2) /offtopic

Comment: @PellMel I'm not a Python programmer so "dedent" is not a term I've come across before. It does appear to be a term of art that really refers to removing/reversing an indent (e.g. by removing whitespace on the left of a string); this is described as "unindenting", which I prefer, in other answers.

Comment: exdent was commonly used in my undergrad typography work; it's used in the question, ex and out have the same meaning, which together and given this is english makes it a word with the same definition as outdent: hanging paragraph by deduct leading line space all the way into the margin. White space is fun to mess with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A search for antonyms unearths Dan Bron's suggestion, [*outdent*](http://www.synonyms.net/antonyms/indent).

> **Outdent** *verb*
>   To indent negatively, bring towards the margin. *By default, the summary tasks are bold and outdented, and the subtasks are indented beneath them.*
>   [- wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/outdent)

The link also defines the noun form as *hanging paragraph*, but it would sound a little odd to say that the code block should be *hung*, not least because of the association between *hanging code* and *buggy code*.

Although the word *outdent* is [not widely used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=outdent%2Chugest&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coutdent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chugest%3B%2Cc0), it has a credible reference, namely, [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Indent-paragraphs-06d6109c-d52e-4e4c-a7b8-697d675b565b), which produces a word processor that *is* widely used:

> You can also create a negative indent (also known as an outdent), which pulls the paragraph out toward the left margin.

If you are *undoing* an indent, the line would be *unindented*, as MatthewC notes. It would be odd, though to describe the very first line of code as *unindented* without prior *indenting*. For a typeset paragraph, *outdent* doesn't assume a prior *indent*, though calling it *negatively indented* sounds more fluent. In your case, namely, "where the first line is set further left than the remainder of the paragraph/block", if that first line starts in the same column as the line before it, you might simply say that it is *not indented*.

Take this block for example, with line numbers purely for reference:

```
1        void f() {
2            init();
3    // TODO: add exception-handling
4            helloWorld();
5        }
```

Line 1 is **not indented**, lines 2 and 4 are **indented**, line 3 is **outdented** or **negatively indented**, and line 5 is **unindented**.

Comment: The reason there is no similar antonym here is that the word *indent* comes from the Latin *in + dentare*, the same root as *dent* meaning tooth, and all things to do with teeth *dentist*, and something being *dented*. So it has to do with implosion inwards, like something which has been bitten. I haven't been able to find an equivalent Latin word meaning *bashed outwards*.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as I think "outdented" is a good description of the situation I'm trying to describe, and also for the code block with comparison of indented, outdented, and unindented.

Comment: @RobGilliam Thanks! Just a follow-up thought: the *first* line of code in a file may be said to be *unindented* in the stative sense the same way a symphony may be *unfinished*, but not in the dynamic sense of an *undo* unless it had previously been indented.

Answer (score 3):

> As a long time programmer, the only term I've ever heard used is *unindented*.

*Unindent* makes it clear that you are referring to the opposite of the word *indent*, and not referring to some type of formatting.

*outdent* sounds like a text formatting word, not a **code** formatting word.

> *Unindent* is clear, and programmer-friendly.

Comment: I disagree. I think the OP is looking for a word he can use to describe code that is not indented, not just for a word that is an antonym. The word the OP wants must be usable in a context and conversation in a development environment.

Comment: I removed that comment just now, because on second reading the question, I changed my mind. +1

Comment: Don't remove it! I think it's a good point to make, and our conversation can help other users become more insightful about this question.

Comment: Especially as I was actually reading this yesterday when the comment disappeared! (Confusing)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a single-word adjective in common usage that describes what you want; I've always taken notes in this style, and if you said "outdented" to me (the closest thing, as others have pointed out) it would definitely take me a minute. Officially, this style is referred to as a *hanging indent*: http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/H/hanging_indent.html

But I've never seen it in any form other than the noun, so you might have to reconstruct some sentences.

Comment: I think this covers cases where all but the first line is indented relative to the rest of the text (hence the upvote), but probably doesn't apply if the first line is outdented relative to the rest of the text, with the rest of the paragraph in line.