# Indent and Outdent

Tags: synonyms

I am creating a WYSIWYG editor.

I am looking for a word to collectively describe "Indent" and "Outdent" (aside from "Indent").

To illustrate what I am looking for, I group the concepts of "Bold", "Italic" and "Underline" into what I call "Emphasis".

Comment: "Margin"?   "Left margin"?   "First line left margin"?

Comment: Margin is close but I think it implies that you can customize the margin in all directions.  Left Margin is more specific but again, it would seem to suggest that the other sides of margin could be customized as well -

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "Indent" and "Outdent". I have heard the term *outdent* used to describe the **action** of reducing the *indent* (i.e. pressing `shift-tab`). In terms of margins, there can be only *indent*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out the following post: [What is the opposite word to "indent"—"outdent" or "unindent"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149511/what-is-the-opposite-word-to-indent-outdent-or-unindent).

@BoldBen has offered a solid answer, but I'll try the following anyway, recognizing that it's iffy.

It would appear that the hypernym of *indentation* and *outdentation* is ***dentation***.

The dictionary definitions of ***dentation*** don't apply directly to your situation. However, it would seem that the same logic that gave rise to *indentation* as you're using it, and that seems to have given rise much more recently, by obvious extension, to *outdentation*, could be used to justify *dentation*.

So how about **dentation**? It could catch on.

Comment: ***dentation*** sounds like something a *dentist* would do.

Comment: Very interesting!  This sounds like a winner!

Answer (score 3):

How about **Alignment** or **Text Alignment**? You could then include **justfication** under the same heading if your intention is to reduce the number of headings or button groupings.

If you want to keep justification and indentation separate you could use **Indentation** since indenting *increases* the *degree* of indentation and outdenting *decreases* it. If your editor will allow outdenting past the left justification of the paragraph, or even into the left margin, you will then create negative indentation, but the concept will still hold.

**Margin** was suggested above but, for me, margins are part of the page settings rather than aspects of the text. As I said outdenting into the left margin is merely negative indentation.