# Is there a word for an existing word to which one gives a newly coined meaning?

Tags: single-word-requests

A ***neologism*** is a newly coined word or expression. Is there a word for an existing word to which one gives a newly coined meaning, and perhaps a different pronunciation?

An example from a [recent post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/350847/indent-and-outdent) (reworded):

> What is the hypernym of "indentation" and "outdentation" in text
>   editing? "Dentation" is an obvious possibility, but none of the
>   dictionary definitions have the desired meaning.
>
> It would seem that the same logic that gave rise to "indentation", and
>   that seems to have given rise much more recently to "outdentation",
>   could be used to justify "dentation".

In any event, the example aside, is there a word for an existing word to which one gives a newly coined meaning, and perhaps a different pronunciation?

Answer (score 3):

In linguistics, this is known as **semantic shift** or **semantic change**.

> Semantic change (also semantic shift, semantic progression or semantic drift) is the evolution of word usage—usually to the point that the modern meaning is radically different from the original usage. In diachronic (or historical) linguistics, semantic change is a change in one of the meanings of a word.

[Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change)]